# linux program not running at boot time

Tags: linux, bash, init.d, rc.d

I have a few scripts: `collection.sh` `start.sh` `script1.sh` and `script2.sh`. I have these set up to run at boot time so that:

- `collection.sh` calls `start.sh`
- `start.sh` calls both `script?.sh`

collection is set up by the following:

```
$ cp collection.sh /etc/init.d/
$ update-rc.d collection.sh defaults 99
```

If I run the collection.sh manually (i.e. `$ . /etc/init.d/collection.sh`) then everything works as expected, but if I reboot or do a full shutdown and start the computer then collection.sh runs but start.sh never runs.

To clarify, here is an example of what each script looks like:

- `collection.sh`:

  ```
  . /path/to/start.sh &
  ```
- `start.sh`:

  ```
  ./script1.sh &
  ./script2.sh &
  ```
- `script1.sh/script2.sh`:

  ```
  while :
  do
      #does some stuff here
      #yes this is an infinite loop
  done
  ```

I have print statements that have confirmed that `collection.sh` starts (twice actually) and `start.sh` never starts.

I have also confirmed, using `ps aux | grep collection.sh` that `collection.sh` does complete.

Comment: What happens if you execute the script `/etc/init.d/collection.sh` instead of sourcing it `. /etc/init.d/collection.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

You may have problem with paths.

change PATH in start.sh or use full paths in start.sh to start script[12].sh

You don't mention which distribution you're using (each one  is slightly different) -- a sledgehammer approach is sometimes putting lines in /etc/rc.local.